# onSubmit not triggered on form loaded with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, dom-events

I use AJAX to load an external HTML file, containing a form, into another HTML file. The form HTML looks something like this:

```
<form id="..." name="..." onsubmit="postUsingAJAX(x,y,x); return false;">
```

Loading works fine. However, the `onSubmit` code is not executed when the form is submitted, same thing with `onClick` handlers on the submit button; no event listeners seems to be triggered. Is this the way things work when HTML is loaded through AJAX or am I doing something wrong?

A possible work-around would be to do:

```
theFormObject.addEventListener('submit', function...)
```

but I can't figure out how to make the form NOT submit after the callback is fired. How can I make it wait for a return value (or rather, feed it "return false" no matter what happens in the callback function)?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like an error in function postUsingAJAX. Code "return false" will not executes. To continue properly work after error you should use try..catch statement. Example:

```
function postUsingAJAX() {
    try {
        // dangerous code
    } catch (e) {
        // report about error
    }
}

<form onsubmit="postUsingAJAX(); return false;">
```

Comment: You might consider further documenting this for novices coming through Google.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AJAX, my guess is that you don't want the form to take the user to a new page - you want it to call the processing page and update the current page accordingly.  What you should do instead is create the entire form without any `<form>` tags.  Then, using the `<button>` tag (example: `<button id="whatever">Whatever</button>`) attach a click event listener to that button to do the AJAX stuff.  That's the way that I always do AJAX calls with a form that the user is filling in.

Comment: It looks like he is taking care of this using "return false" in the javascript for his onsubmit handler - so the form should be prevented from posting through the normal process, unless there is a javascript error.

Comment: Yeah, but I've actually tried doing the onsubmit with a return false and that neveerrrr worked for me - it would always go through.  Best to just avoid it straightaway.